# React +(Router) without webpack or browserify

Tags: reactjs, browserify, webpack, react-router

Is it possible to use react with ReactRouter, without using browserify or webpack.
I am following the documentation from http://rackt.github.io/react-router they require react and react-router (`require('react-router');`). If I use browerifly my generated bundle is about 1MB filesize, which sounds like a lot.

So is it possible to get reactrouter working with including compiled JS from a CDN like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/0.13.3/ReactRouter.js, instead of bundle all requirements by myself ? If i try to make it work with a CDN, I get an error that Route is not defined. But it looks like it is exported in the cdn file.

I would like to compile my JSX/ES6 react components include the ReactRouter and react JS-files from a cdn and only bundle my components into a new js file.

Is this possible or is browserify and webpack the right way to setup the project ? (I looked at several github repos). I got some doubts because there is no installation guide on http://rackt.github.io/react-router/

like this pseudo html:

```
<head>
    CND :include react, react-router
    my code combinded.js
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using the prebuilt version from the CDN, the library is exported onto `window.ReactRouter`. So, `Route` is defined on `window.ReactRouter.Route`.

Since React Router also depends on React, using the CDN/browser build will also require that `React` is available on `window.React`.

That said, the CDN version you linked to is, itself, generated with webpack, so I don't expect that you'd gain any file size improvements. You might look into minification/dead code elimination on your browserify bundle to see if it decreases the file size.

Answer (score 2):

One additional info I want to share is the possibility to use externals (https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) in webpack config.
I use it as following:

```
externals: {
  "react": "React",
  "react/addons": "React",
  "reflux" : "Reflux"
}
```

this results in a smaller bundle and you can use react from a CDN as asked in my question. This also decreases the buildtime with gulp.